# gnome-keyring use unsafe storage for all users

Tags: ldap, gnome-keyring

I'm running a large number of Ubuntu desktops for a school. We use ldap and somehow gnome-keyring always gets out of sync and starts prompting for passwords. Eventually it seems to sync again, but I get calls all the time because of a mysterious password box showing up.

I know how to set it to unsafe storage for one user, but is there a way to force this on all users? Something in /etc/skel would be fine

I suspect the reason it gets out of sync is because we use a little web app to change passwords. This is necessary because it also changes Google and Samba passwords for the user.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a bug report for this:
[322827](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/322827)

But it hasn't seen much action.
Unfortunately, the old password needs to be known to remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've commented on the bug report. I'll keep looking for a solution/workaround.

Comment: Just thinking - there is pam_gnome-keyring to handle seahorse and pam_ldap for ldap, but there is also pam_google from Google OS. Could you perhaps use that and get rid of the web app?

Comment: pam_google, very cool I'll have to play with it. But I still just need a traditional LDAP for some things. Also lets say we have a computer lab where students use computers, but often different ones. If a student changes the password on one, we will still see a gnome-keyring out of sync problem, unless perhaps we mount gnome-keyring on NFS.